# SpagoBI: End user customized web page

Tags: web-applications, fiware, spagobi

I need to create a dynamic customized web page for my end user, I dont know how to do that under SpagoBI.

I know that I can configure a user menu and to add elements to it: an analytic document, a static html page etc.

But if I want for example to show a web page containing the following:

```
my data: my data value
```

- my data: is a static text
- my data value: a value got from the data base

how can I do that on spagoBI?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can develop a report and link it the user's menu.
As an alternative, you can develop a document to be executed by the accessible engine: actually this engine just applies a XSLT transformation, therefore you can generate a HTML page starting from data retrived by a dataset.
Hope this helps.
Best regards
Davide